# How do I make pandas installed via Anaconda usable by PyCharm?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, anaconda

I'm on Windows 10 and have installed Anaconda3 (2016-1). When I use Spyder that Anaconda installed, `import pandas` works.

From PyCharm I however can't `import pandas`. PyCharm is set to use `C:\Users\Chris>C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda3\envs\Conda\python.exe`.

If I call the exe directly I also can't `import pandas` despite it being in the Anaconda3 dictionary.

```
C:\Users\Chris>C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda3\envs\Conda\python.exe
Python 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

What do I have to do, that I can `import pandas`?

Comment: Do you use a separate environment created with `conda` when you use Spyder? If you do, then it is a different interpreter.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli : I use the Spyder that Anaconda installed. I don't know whether Anaconda installs it with a special enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I set the path to `C:\Users\Chris>C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda3\python.exe` instead of using a virtual enviroment with `C:\Users\Chris>C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda3\envs\Conda\python.exe` as PyCharm suggests.

Comment: which path are you talking about here?